# Not able to block ipAddress:port/#/register through nginx

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I am using an angular js application, and I want to block a url for specific ip address through Nginx.  url: ipAddress:port/#/register.

The problem I am facing to block the url is:  There is # in the middle so Nginx is not able to detect the url.

I wrote this configuration inside the nginx.config

```
location /#/register
{
allow   122.1.1.1;
deny    all;
proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
}
```

I have tried to put all kind of regex instead of #, but still, I am missing something here.

Please suggest me the possible ways that I can detect it and block it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : When ipAddress:port/#/register is called for the first time the first thing that happens is to load all the controllers in browser memory, and then angular routes it to the specific controller. I blocked the api call that controller makes.

I could have done it from controller side. But can be easily hacked. So did it form nginx side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot capture that. Because it is never sent to the server. These are HTML anchors and they are used for redirecting you to a position on the page or for routing in angular. Consider the url `http://192.168.33.100/test/#/register`

When i hit it using curl

```
$ curl -vL "http://192.168.33.100/test/#/register"
*   Trying 192.168.33.100...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.33.100 (192.168.33.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.33.100
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Or in browser

[image: Browser image]

As you can see `#` and anything after that is not sent to the server at all. Also when you use `ipAddress:port/#/register` that will render a page and that page will make an API request to perform the action.

So you should target protecting the API that gets called by angular and you should try to handle the logic in your angular routes

Comment: Yes, It never shows in URL after #. But when it hits back end in some portion of the request the 'register' goes. That is how the angular routes understand where to redirect. I think, I need to find out in which portion of the request that is coming

Comment: Use DevTools in Chrome and watch the Network tab. You will see what call is your Angular App making for this